# C# DrawMenu() how to set a key to hide the overlay?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, overlay

I want to set a key which will hide the complete overlay of the program as I need functions that are displayed in the menu which will have drawn but then I want to hide it.

```
// Begin Draw
                device.BeginDraw();
                device.Clear(new Color4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

                // Check Window State
                if (IsMinimized == false)
                {

                    // Draw Menu
                    DrawMenu();

                }

                // End Draw
                device.EndDraw();
                CalculateFrameRate();
```

Any suggestions?

Greetings